# SetDate in textBox?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2, gwt-widgets

I create widgets for date for my project.

n using the same widget for setProperty and getProperty of a object.

```
public TextBox getTimeTxtbx() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        timebx =new TextBox();

        timebx.setReadOnly(true);
        final PopupPanel popupPanel=new PopupPanel(true);
        final DatePicker datePicker=new DatePicker();

        datePicker.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {

            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Date date=event.getValue();
                timebx.setText(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").format(date));
                popupPanel.hide();
            }


        });
        popupPanel.setWidget(datePicker);
        timebx.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String strDate = timebx.getText();
                System.out.println(" strDate " +strDate);
                DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("[EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy]");
                try {  
                      Date selDate = (Date)format.parse(strDate); 
                      datePicker.setValue(selDate, true);
                    } catch(Exception pe){
                     // setting current date
                        System.out.println("error" +pe);
                     datePicker.setValue(new Date(), true);
                    }
                int x=timebx.getAbsoluteLeft();
                int y=timebx.getAbsoluteTop();
                popupPanel.setPopupPosition(x, y+20);
                popupPanel.show();
            }
        });
        return timebx;
    }
    public void setTimebx(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        timebx.setText(string);
    }
```

I am adding this widgets in flexTable in different gui class

```
flexTable.setWidget(i, j,textBoxDisplay.getTimeTxtbx());
textBoxDisplay.setTimebx(customProperty.getValues().toString());
```

In a flexTable , this above code is inside a `iterator` and called **Twice**.
[image]

Like in Image : testDate an received on.

When i click on testDate the value of Received On is Changed

---

Edited

```
public ListBox getBooleanBox() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        selectBoolean = new ListBox(false);
        //selectBoolean.setName(title);
        selectBoolean.setStyleName("cmis-Customproperties-TextBox");
        selectBoolean.setSize("150px", "20px");
        selectBoolean.addItem("True","True");
        selectBoolean.addItem("False", "False");
        return selectBoolean;
    }
    public void setBooleanBox(String value){
         int itemCount = selectBoolean.getItemCount();
         for(int i = 0 ;i < itemCount;i++){
             if(selectBoolean.getItemText(i).equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
                 selectBoolean.setSelectedIndex(i);
             }
         }
    }
```

adding in flexTable

```
customPropertyTabel.setWidget(i, j,textBoxDisplay.getBooleanBox());
textBoxDisplay.setBooleanBox(removeSymbol(customProperty.getValues().toString()));
```

and this is working perfectly fine.
I got the correct values.

Comment: @Keppil when i click on the text box of testDate the popUp is on the textBox of ReceivedOn ant the value of receivedOn text box changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a referencing issue in the implementation.

On your second iteration of `getTimeTxtbx` (when you create Received On textbox) you have set the local variable `timebx` in `textBoxDisplay` instance to a new reference which is the Received On textbox. Your `datePicker`'s `onValueChange` implementation set the text on `timebx`, hence the Received On textbox gets set instead of the `testingDate` textbox on your second iteration.

Try use a new instance of `TextBoxDisplay` instead during the iteration.

```
TextBoxDisplay textBoxDisplay = new TextBoxDisplay();
flexTable.setWidget(i, j,textBoxDisplay.getTimeTxtbx());
textBoxDisplay.setTimebx(customProperty.getValues().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me `textBoxDisplay` is the same widget instance for both testingDate and receivedOn. Meaning if the receivedOn is added it overrides the testingDate, hence you get the popup when you click on the icon of testingDate. So you need a `textBoxDisplay` for both testingDate and receivedOn, like: `textBoxDisplayTestingDate` and `textBoxDisplayReceivedOn`

Comment: I also had suspicion about instantiating the objects

Comment: i am doing the similar coding with boolean list  .. AnimationEnabled and testingBoolean.. It is working fine.. Plz check the edited Area.

Comment: With the boolean list you only initialize the listbox and don't add handlers. So the `selectBoolean` is not accessed outside the initialization phase. But `selectBoolean` will be the last initialized listbox. So if you add a change handler it will mean if any of you listbox changes value and you read the value of `selectBoolean` in your handler it will read the value of the last initialized listbox.